# Saída de uma função void

Tags: c, funções, return, int, void

Estou programando um caça palavra e um problemas na função void está dificultando. No código uso funções pra varrer a matriz em todos os sentidos e me retorna as coordenadas inicias e finais ou saírem da função e iniciar a leitura em outro sentido, ai nasce minha dúvida, é possível sair da função, como indiquei com #####, ou faço uma função int com return 0?
Me ajudem com esse código e se observarem outro erro no código me sinalizem.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void Norte (char cacapalavra[][100], char palavra[], int pc, int pl) {
    int i, j, n, k;
    j = pc; k = 0;
    n = strlen(palavra);

    for (i = pl; i < i+n; i++) {
            if (cacapalavra [i][j] != palavra[k]) ######;
            else k++;
    }
    printf ("%d %d", pc, pl);
    printf("%d %d", i, j);
}

void Sul (char cacapalavra[][100], char palavra[], int pc, int pl) {
    int i, j, n, k;
    j = pc; k = 0;
    n = strlen(palavra);

    for (i = pl; i < i+n; i++) {
            if (cacapalavra [i][j] != palavra[k]) #####;
            else k++;
    }
    printf ("%d %d", pc, pl);
    printf("%d %d", i, j);
}

void Leste (char cacapalavra[][100], char palavra[], int pc, int pl) {
    int i, j, n, k;
    i = pl; k = 0;
    n = strlen(palavra);

    for (j = pc; j < j+n; j++) {
            if (cacapalavra [i][j] != palavra[k]) #####;
            else k++;
    }
    printf ("%d %d", pc, pl);
    printf("%d %d", i, j);
}

void Oeste (char cacapalavra[][100], char palavra[], int pc, int pl) {
    int i, j, n, k;
    i = pl; k = 0;
    n = strlen(palavra);

    for (j = pc; j < j+n; j--) {
            if (cacapalavra [i][j] != palavra[k]) #####;
            else k++;
    }
    printf ("%d %d", pc, pl);
    printf("%d %d", i, j);
}

void Nordeste (char cacapalavra[][100], char palavra[], int pc, int pl) {
     int i, j, n, k;
     k = 0;
     n = strlen(palavra);

     for (i = pl, j = pc; i < i+n; j++, i--) {
             if (cacapalavra [i][j] != palavra[k]) #####;
            else k++;
     }
     printf ("%d %d", pc, pl);
     printf("%d %d", i, j);
}

void Noroeste (char cacapalavra[][100], char palavra[], int pc, int pl) {
     int i, j, n, k;
     k = 0;
     n = strlen(palavra);

     for (i = pl, j = pc; i < i+n; j--, i--) {
            if (cacapalavra [i][j] != palavra[k]) #####;
            else k++;
    }
    printf ("%d %d", pc, pl);
    printf("%d %d", i, j);
}

void Sudeste (char cacapalavra[][100], char palavra[], int pc, int pl) {
     int i, j, n, k;
     k = 0;
     n = strlen(palavra);

     for (i = pl, j = pc; i < i+n; j--, i++) {
             if (cacapalavra [i][j] != palavra[k]) #####;
             else k++;
     }
    printf ("%d %d", pc, pl);
    printf("%d %d", i, j);
}

void Sudoeste (char cacapalavra[][100], char palavra[], int pc, int pl) {
     int i, j, n, k;
     k = 0;
     n = strlen(palavra);

     for (i = pl, j = pc; i < i+n; j++, i++) {
             if (cacapalavra [i][j] != palavra[k]) ######;
             else k++;
     }
     printf ("%d %d", pc, pl);
     printf("%d %d", i, j);
}

int main () {

    char cacapalavra [100][100];
    char palavra [100];
    int i, j, k, n, pc, pl;
    k = 0;

    scanf ("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
          for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                scanf ("%c", &cacapalavra[i][j]);

    scanf ("%s", palavra);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (palavra[k] == cacapalavra[i][j]) {
                pc = j; pl = i;
                Norte(cacapalavra, palavra, pc, pl);
                Sul(cacapalavra, palavra, pc, pl);
                Leste(cacapalavra, palavra, pc, pl);
                Oeste(cacapalavra, palavra, pc, pl);
                Nordeste(cacapalavra, palavra, pc, pl);
                Noroeste(cacapalavra, palavra, pc, pl);
                Sudeste(cacapalavra, palavra, pc, pl);
                Sudoeste(cacapalavra, palavra, pc, pl);

               }
         }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Marcelo você conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Não completamente Laís, ainda não acertei as posições, meu programa só tá lendo parte das palavras.

Answer (score 4):

Para abandonar uma função que devolve `void` a meio, usa `return`

```
        if (cacapalavra [i][j] != palavra[k]) return;
```